# renewcommand in recursive function

Tags: expansion, recursion

I'm trying to write a function `DoForList` that iterates over a comma seperated list and calls a handler function for each item.

Some of those handler functions do subsequent calls to `DoForList` thus `\renewcommand` overwrites the existing `\Handle` function, and the items after the recursive call get passed to the wrong function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\def\Handle{}
\newcommand{\PrintDebug}[2]{\typeout{DoForList: [#1] #2}}
\newcounter{step}
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoForList}{O{\PrintDebug}m}{%
   \setcounter{step}{0}
    \renewcommand{\Handle}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{step}
        %%%Call the handler function with <step>, <item>, <list>
        #1{##1}{\arabic{step}}%
    }
    \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\Handle\expandafter{#2}%
     \setcounter{step}{0}
}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
    \ifnum #2 = 1%
       \textit{#2:#1}%
    \else%
        , #2:#1%
     \fi%
}
\newcommand{\foobar}[2]{%
    #2  --\DoForList[\foo]{a,b,c,d}\\
}
\begin{document}
\DoForList[\foobar]{1,2,3,4,5} 
\end{document}
```

This prints

1 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
*1:2* , 2:3 , 3:4 , 4:5

Instead of

1 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
2 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
3 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
4 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
5 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d

What happens is that `\DoForList[\foobar]{1,2,3,4,5}` calls `\foobar{1}`

At this point, `\Handle` in `DoForList` is defined to call `\foobar`.

Then `\foobar` recursively calls `\DoForList[\foo]{a,b,c,d}`.

This redefines `\Handle` and which calls `\foo{a}`, `\foo{b}` ... `\foo{d}`.

When `\foo` processed all items (a,b,c,d), `\foobar` should be called with his next item `\foobar{2}`, but instead, `\foo` get's called with the remaining items *(2,3,4,5)* because `\Handle` got redefined in the recursive call, and still passes everything to `\foo`

`clist_map_function` handles recursion fine, but i can't use it because i need to pass extra arguments to `\foo`.

So instead of redefining `\Handle` in a recursive call, i would like to introduce a new command `\HandlerRecursion1`, `HandlerRecursion2`.

I tried using `\csname` to generate a unique `\Handle` macro for each level of recursion, but i'm an absolute beginner in Latex and a bit lost in how you would pass that handler to forcsvlist

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoForList}{O{\PrintDebug}mO{0}O{9999999}}{%
    \def\HandlerName{Handle\arabic{LevelOfRecursion}}
    \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter{\csname\HandlerName\endcsname}[1]{...}
    %%% something like this?
    \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter -> \csname\HandlerName\endcsname <- \expandafter{#2}%
}
```

If `\csname\HandlerName\endcsname` could be expanded and passed to `\forcsvlist` everything would work fine, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: This seems to be an XY-question; you have more chances to get a solution to your problem if you explain it clearly. Showing your attempt is good, but perhaps it's easier to look at the problem from a different point of view.

Comment: Again, you're trying to explain your attempt at a solution, but not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX3 team has already provided what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DoForList}{O{\PrintDebug}m}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\PrintDebug}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1:( }

\begin{document}

\DoForList[\foo]{a,b,c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure what your aim is with `\foo` and `\foobar` being defined with two arguments: the handler macro given as argument to `\DoForList` should have just one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks promising and clean. The aim of the two arguments is to pass the index of the item in the list to`\foo`, in order to be able to e.g. treat the first item in the list differently or to break out of the recursion early.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Sorry, but I can't understand what you're after.

Comment: Thank you! I found a solution and added it as answer, i was thinking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\csname` to save your function in a temporary variable with a unique name and call that from within `\Handler` instead of directly invoking `#1`

Instead of calling `#1{##1}{\arabic{step}}%`

You would first save `#1` in a variable

`\expandafter\def\csname Handler\arabic{recursion}\endcsname{#1}`

Where `recursion` is a counter that counts the level of recursion.

Inside your `\Handler` you would call the function using `\csuse`

`\csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}{##1}{\arabic{step}}%`

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\def\Handle{}
\newcommand{\PrintDebug}[2]{\typeout{DoForList: [#1] #2}}
\newcounter{step}
\newcounter{recursion}
\setcounter{recursion}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DoForList}{O{\PrintDebug}m}{%
    \setcounter{step}{0}  
    \stepcounter{recursion}
    \expandafter\def\csname Handler\arabic{recursion}\endcsname{#1}
    \renewcommand{\Handle}[1]{%
            \stepcounter{step}
            %%%Call the handler function with <step>, <item>, <list>
            \csuse{Handler\arabic{recursion}}{##1}{\arabic{step}}%
        }
    \expandafter\forcsvlist\expandafter\Handle\expandafter{#2}%
    \setcounter{step}{0}
    \addtocounter{recursion}{-1}
}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
    \ifnum #2 = 1%
        \textit{#2:#1}%
    \else%
        , #2:#1%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand{\foobar}[2]{%
    #1  --\DoForList[\foo]{a,b,c,d}\\
}

\begin{document}
\DoForList[\foobar]{1,2,3,4,5} 
\end{document}
```

---

This prints

1 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
2 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
3 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
4 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d
5 -- *1:a* , 2:b , 3:c , 4:d